# Mobile app not scrolling

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, scroll

I have a simple equation reference app that I would like to make mobile suitable, but the user cannot scroll to the front or side. This is the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function onBodyLoad()
        {       
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady()
        {
        }

        </script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes;" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
</head>
```

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes;" />`

To this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

I believe the issue is your `maximum-scale=1.0` attribute. Because that conflicts with the `user-scalable=yes` attribute.

More info: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

Comment: Well, I've tried using it, but it only works for the first page. The entire app is in one file, so normally I'd assume the contents of the header apply to the entire thing, but apparently there's some separation between the pages. The entire app is ~1000 lines so I'm not sure it'd be feasible to place it up here.

Comment: jQueryMobile uses AJAX page transitions, so I've had trouble with things on certain pages not being carried over to others. You'd have to post more of the code to be able to diagnose that.

Comment: Hypothetically, how would you approach the problem? Maybe I can see what's up.

Comment: I've built an app in jQueryMobile for submission to the iTunes App Store, and I just used the same header code in all the HTML files. You mentioned that it's all one file, but how does that work if you say it only works on the first page?

Comment: Ah, I see. Damn ethics. I'm wholly against using others' code, but I can't deny the temptation to ask you for it right now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ethics? Open source is all about sharing code. Here's a fiddle of my header: http://jsfiddle.net/nickcoxdotme/UJkTT/ . Do you need more?

Comment: 0_0

Not at all! Thank you so much!